# Почему в heroku не запускает django-приложение?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Пытаюсь развернуть приложение  django с админкой. git [здесь][1]

В консоли heroku logs

```html
2020-08-22T14:12:16.260338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=55e093b5-3c5d-4941-829b-8db157f1f05a fwd="178.44.178.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-22T14:12:17.484462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=6dbd5ba0-ad88-4b01-ba3d-89245413d949 fwd="178.44.178.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-22T14:12:46.770903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/tasks" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=3e7612b3-d31c-4778-b89e-ee510b480b65 fwd="178.44.178.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-22T14:12:47.952722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=1ea88a43-6c96-4c9b-bee7-cd7b081da45d fwd="178.44.178.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Локально все открывается. Специально отключил статические файлы, зная, что с ними heroku не работает.

Comment: было бы полезно увидеть логи когда дайно стартует. и что прописано в procfile или heroku.yml видимо по какой то причине джанга не запустилась впринципе

Comment: да и хероку раздает статику

Comment: @Mikhail Lazko  вот проект на гитхабе: github.com/Marlin005/todoapp  Heroku logs: pastebin.com/Jp5uE71R

Comment: `web: gunicorn damp-beach-23703.wsgi --log-file`  куда то не туда указывает ваш procfile `damp-beach-23703` такого приложения у вас нет попробуйте указать `web: gunicorn todoapp.wsgi`

Comment: @Mikhail Lazko поменял снова wsqi сайт открылся, но когда через bash создал createsuperuser на стр.входа error 500

Comment: по моему это уже другой вопрос, и тут опять надо смотреть логи и т.д. полагаю первоначальный вопрос решен. Общий совет, идентифицируйте ошибку и погуглити на стек оверфлоу должны быть готовые ответы, главное правильно гуглить